# C++ Multiple Logical Operator

Tags: c++, winapi, logical-operators

I'm rather new to C/C++. I have a segment of my application which doesn't seem to work as I'd want but I cannot understand why.

What I'm looking to do is when the 4 key is in the status of down, I'd like it to carry out the 'idle' function. I'd like the idle function to have 2 outcomes.
If the Up OR Down OR Left OR Right OR LMouse AND RButton then carry out the 'movement rotation operation' code else just carry out the standard idle function.
However within my code, it'll loop this while it's down but the moving() will only ever return 0

I've been messing with it for some time and trying to look on google for answers but I cannot understand why.

Here's my segment of code:

```
int moving()
{
    int u = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP);
    int d = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN);
    int l = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT);
    int r = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT);
    int mr = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RBUTTON);
    int ml = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON);
    if(u == 1 || d == 1 || l == 1 || r == 1 || mr == 1 && ml == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

void idle()
{
    cout << "moving = " << moving() << endl;
    if(moving() == 1)
    {
        cout << "Movement rotation operating." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "This is the idle statement" << endl;
    }

}

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
    if(GetAsyncKeyState('4'))
        {
            cout << "4 Pressed" << endl;
            idle();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should add another return (`return 0`) in your function, just after if.

Comment: Also, check documentation of `GetAsyncKeyState` function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx - it will return not 1 but some code "*If the most significant bit is set, the key is down, and if the least significant bit is set, the key was pressed after the previous call*".

Comment: As in an else{return 0} on the first if() statement within the moving section?

Comment: Additionally to the first comment. I would always make sure that `int SomeFunction()` always explicitly returns 0 if it doesn't return something else already.

Comment: Maybe I should be just using the GetKeyState Function? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic to determine the button combination needs an extra set of parentheses.

```
if(u == 1 || d == 1 || l == 1 || r == 1 || (mr == 1 && ml == 1))
```

Also, `1` will evaluate to `true` so you can say

```
if(u || d || l || r || (mr && ml))
```

You could also make the function return a `bool` since that is really what you're after.

```
bool moving()
{
    // ...
    // code for getting button states
    // ...
    return (u || d || l || r || (mr && ml))
}
```

Comment: His variables are `int`, not `bool`, so `1` will be 1.  (On the other hand, this may not be what he wants.)

Comment: But +1 for the final version,  with just a `return` (although the outer parentheses are superfluous).

Comment: Yes they will be 1, but when you perform a logical operation, e.g. `if (1 && 1)` you will get a boolean result, `true`. Conversely, `0` will evaluate to `false` in the same sense.

Comment: As some other parts of my code will be using the return of 1 I think I'll keep it as int for now, however very good to know as an option. This has resolved my issue. Thank you